# Word for unusable space

Tags: single-word-requests

I am describing a problem regarding locations positioned next to each other where blocks are placed. For a given layout the locations next to blocks are unusable and in the next step no block might be placed here. For example, in the layout:

|_|x|x|_|x|_|_|

The first, fourth and sixth locations cannot be used later. I am looking for a word to describe it. So far i have unusable, or maybe dead space. Is there a better word for this? Thanks in advance!

Example sentence:
In the layout above there are 3 ___. In another layout there is one __ less.

Comment: We need more of a clue as to what these "blocks" are and what rules govern their placement.

Comment: @HotLicks These blocks are shipping containers and the rules of their placements are governed by crane requirements.

Comment: I was going to suggest "dead space", but I see that you have included it in your question. I think it's a good fit.

Comment: What's wrong with 'unusable'?

Comment: and a fancy ...inutile!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Things that can be used are available for use. Those that can't are [**unavailable**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unavailable) for use:

> not able to be used or obtained; not at someone's disposal

This is a very general term that can be used in a variety of different ways. So, I think it will definitely work in your context.

Comment: Just as a note to this, not a crticism: unavailable suggests that they *might* become available at some point, eg when the current user stops using them, which doesn't quite fit the question.  Perhaps "permanently unavailable" would be better.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Thank you for your suggestion. I guess, we'll have to leave that to the OP's discretion.

Answer (score 8):

From Oxford Dictionary (online):

> [Reserved](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/reserved) *adj.* : 2. kept specially for a particular purpose or person.

- The **reserved** locations are spaces which *may not be used* for any other purpose at any time, as they are already serving their purpose.

Comment: In a similar vein, I think 'earmarked' could work as well. As in "these spaces are earmarked for *X*, so should not be used".

Comment: @Sean Burton ~ That's a great answer, you should post it!

Comment: Note that the difference between *reserved* and *unavailable* is that reserved items are usually declared a priori, while items may become unavailable as events unfold.

Answer (score 4):

[out-of-bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_bounds) works.

> outside the playing boundaries of the field

Answer (score 1):

**Restricted**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restricted):

> limited, especially by official rules, laws, etc.

In your case you could say:

> The first, fourth and sixth locations are **restricted**.

Attribution: "Restricted Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed April 05, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/restricted.

Answer (score 1):

How about "void", "void space" or "null space"? Just an idea.

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your word choices, along with corroborating references and examples of usage.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein to the suggestion of 'reserved', you could also use the 'earmarked':

> [Earmark](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/earmarked?s=t): to set aside for a specific purpose, use, recipient, etc.:
>   *to earmark goods for export*.

This would be used like "these spaces are earmarked for X, so should not be used for any other purpose".

Answer (score 0):

How about

> [Unassignable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unassignable) not assignable (Merriam Webster)

or

> [Nonassignable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/nonassignable) not assignable (Merriam Webster)

Because they **are** spaces, but they just can't be allocated or assigned because of your crane.

Other options might be

> [Ineligible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ineligible) : not eligible: 
>   such as
>   a : not qualified for an office or position
>   b : not permitted under football rules to catch a forward pass an ineligible receiver

or just

> [Unusable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unusable) : not capable of being used or fit for use : not usable

Finally, why not use 'unallocatable' or 'unallocable' which I can't find in any dictionary, but seem like perfectly good words for the requirement.

Comment: Use citations in answers, if you please.